# R - Convert Float number to Date

Tags: r, datetime

Wondering if you can give me some light about an outstanding problem I have in R, version 4.0.2. I am moving data from an excel file in a given sharepoint to a local DB. The problem facing is that when reading the file using readxl the columns in the original file as dates (datetime) are being returned as floating point numbers. I need to change the number back to datetime.

Libraries used:

```
library(readxl)
library(odbc)
library(lubridate)
```

**Number**

```
44047.8149884259

44055.2403009259

44048.504537037
```

**Expected result**

```
8/4/2020  7:33:35 PM

8/12/2020  5:46:02 AM

8/5/2020  12:06:32 PM
```

I've tried to use `as_date` with different formats and `as.POSIXct` but don't seem to have an answer.

Thanks in advance for your kindly inputs.

Comment: btw, to use these data in R as *values* (not arbitrary strings), you should be converting them to `POSIXt` format, not a string of that formatting. In R, it will always *represent* the dates and timestamps in a single format, so if you want it to look like this in a report, table, or plot, then think about changing the format at the very last moment. R's `Date` and `POSIXt` classes are numeric-like, meaning they are continuous variables ... once you convert to strings just to get this formatting, you lose that "number"-like behavior.

Comment: `out <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(v1, origin="1970-01-01"))` will do that, then you can adjust `attr(out, "tzone") <- "UTC"` or whichever time zone is more appropriate.

Comment: @r2evans I don't think that solution gives the expected output.  Please check the year

Comment: Good call ... `as.POSIXct(as.Date(v1, origin="1899-12-30"), tz="UTC")`, I forgot it was sourced in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use

```
format(as.POSIXct(v1 * 60 *60 * 24, origin = '1899-12-30', tz = 'UTC'),
        '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
#[1] "08/04/2020 07:33:34 pm" "08/12/2020 05:46:01 am" "08/05/2020 12:06:31 pm"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(44047.8149884259, 44055.2403009259, 44048.504537037)
```